# Shiny showing same result even if I upload new files

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app where extract_text and extract_table functions from R tabulizer package are used. But the problem is in an instance the results from the first file I upload remains, i.e. if I upload a pdf file the desired results appear, but even if I upload a new file the results don't change unless I stop and start a new instance. Here is my server.R code-

```
     shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
        fund<-reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile))
        {return(NULL)} else {
          rr<-extract_text(inFile$datapath, pages =2)
          e1<-extract_tables(inFile$datapath, pages =1)
          e2<-extract_tables(inFile$datapath, pages =2)
          rr<-gsub("\r\n", " ", rr)
          ss<-unlist(strsplit(rr, "Total & WAR:"))
          gr<-grep("Reverse Repo With Bank", ss)

          if (length(gr)>=1) {
            sk<-gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", ss[gr], perl=T) 
            sn<-unlist(strsplit(sk, " ", fixed=T))
            grp<-grep("Limited", sn)
            dm<-matrix(nrow=length(grp), ncol=4)
            party<-c()
            for (i in 1:length(grp)){
              dm[i,]<-sn[(grp[i]+1):(grp[i]+4)]
              party[i]<-paste(sn[(grp[i]-2):(grp[i])],sep="", collapse=" ")
            }
            dm<-as.data.frame(dm)
            names(dm)<-c("Amount", "Rate", "DealDate", "MaturityDate" )
            dm$PartyName<-party
            dm$Tenure<-rep("", times=nrow(dm))
            dm<-dm[,c(5:6,1:4)]
            dn<-data.frame(PartyName="Product Name : Reverse Repo with Bank", Tenure="", Amount="", Rate="", DealDate="", MaturityDate="")
            dnn<-data.frame(PartyName="Total & WAR:", Tenure="", Amount="", Rate="", DealDate="", MaturityDate="")
            dm<-rbind(dn,dm,dnn)
          }


          if (length(e1)>1) {
            l1<-dim(e1[[1]])[1]
            l2<-dim(e1[[2]])[1]
            m<-c(l1,l2)
            e<-e1[[which(m==max(m))]]
          } else {e=e1[[1]]}

          gop<-grep("Party Name", e[,1], fixed=T)
          e<-e[-(1:(gop-1)),]
          e[,3]<-gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", e[,3], perl=T) 

          if (ncol(e)==4){
            ss<-strsplit(e[,3], " ")
            s1<-sapply(ss, function(x) x[1])
            s2<-sapply(ss, function(x) x[2])
            sss<-strsplit(e[,4], " ")
            s1s<-sapply(sss, function(x) x[1])
            s2s<-sapply(sss, function(x) x[2])
            e<-cbind(e[,1:2],s1,s2,s1s,s2s)
          } else if (ncol(e)==5) {
            sss<-strsplit(e[,5], " ")
            s1s<-sapply(sss, function(x) x[1])
            s2s<-sapply(sss, function(x) x[2])
            e<-cbind(e[,1:4],s1s,s2s)
          }
          d<-rbind(e[-1,],e2[[1]][-1,])
          d<-as.data.frame(d)
          colnames(d)<-c("PartyName", "Tenure", "Amount", "Rate", "DealDate", "MaturityDate")


          if (length(gr)>=1){
            d<-rbind(d,dm)
          }
          row.names(d)<-1:nrow(d)

          d$Rate<-as.numeric(as.character(d$Rate))
          w<-which(d$Rate>7)
          d<-d[-w,]
          d$IncomeType<-rep(NA, nrow(d))
          d$Rate[is.na(d$Rate)]<-0
          levels<-c(-1,1,5,7)
          labels<-c("Invalid","Low Income", "Medium Income")
          d$IncomeType<-cut(d$Rate, levels, labels)
          d$Period<-as.Date(d$MaturityDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")-Sys.Date()
          d$Period[is.na(d$Period)]<-1
          levels1<-c(-50,-1,1,15,30,5000)
          labels1<-c("Already Matured", "Within 1 Day", "Within 2 to 15 Days", "Within 16 to 30 Days", "More than 1 Month")
          d$MaturityType<-cut(as.numeric(d$Period), levels1, labels1)

          m<-grep("Product Name : Commercial Paper", d[,1], fixed=T)
          d<-d[-m,]
          g1<-grep("Product Name",d[,1], fixed=T)
          name<-d[g1,1]
          name<-as.character(name)
          name<-sapply(strsplit(name,": "), "[", 2)
          g2<-grep("Total & WAR",d[,1], fixed=T)
          w<-which(d[,1]=="Product Name : Call Borrowing with Bank")
          if (length(w)>=1){
            d<-d[-(g1[which(g1==w)]:g2[which(g1==w)]),]
            name<-name[-which(g1==w)]
            g1<-grep("Product Name",d[,1], fixed=T)
            g2<-grep("Total & WAR",d[,1], fixed=T)
          }
          Product<-c()
          for (i in 1: length(g1)) {
            Product[(g1[i]):(g2[i])]<-name[i]
          }
          d$Product<-Product

          d<-d[!(is.na(d$DealDate)|d$DealDate==""),]


          d$Amount<-as.numeric(gsub(",", "", d$Amount))
          Remaining<-as.Date(d$MaturityDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")-Sys.Date()
          d$Remaining<-ifelse(is.na(Remaining)!=TRUE, Remaining, "ON CALL")


          d<-d[order(d$IncomeType,d$Product),]
          d<-d[,c(1,10,3,4,7,5,6,11)]
          d$DealDate<-as.character(d$DealDate)
          d$MaturityDate<-as.character(d$MaturityDate)

          d$Period<-as.Date(d$MaturityDate, format="%d/%m/%Y")-Sys.Date()
          d$Period[is.na(d$Period)]<-1
          levels1<-c(-5000,0,1,15,30,5000)
          labels1<-c("Already Matured", "Matures Next Day", "In Between 2 to 15 Days", "In Between 16 to 30 Days", "More than 1 Month")
          d$MaturityType<-cut(as.numeric(d$Period), levels1, labels1)

          d1<-d[,1:8]
          d1<-d1[order(d$IncomeType,d$Product),]

          rate<-sum(as.numeric(d1$Amount)*as.numeric(d1$Rate)/sum(as.numeric(d1$Amount)))

          d1<-as.data.frame(apply(d1, 2, function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)), stringsAsFactors = F)

          d1$MaturityDate[is.na(d1$MaturityDate)]<-""


          d1[(nrow(d1)+1),]<-c("Total","",sum(as.numeric(d1$Amount)),rate, rep("", times=4))
          row.names(d1)<-1:nrow(d1)

          tt<-daply(d,.(IncomeType, Product), summarize, sum(Amount),.drop_i = F)
          tt<-tt[-1,]
          rrr<-rowSums(apply(tt,2, as.numeric))
          tt<-cbind(tt,Total=rrr)
          cc<-colSums(apply(tt, 2, as.numeric))
          tt<-rbind(tt,Total=cc)

          tt1<-daply(d,.(IncomeType, MaturityType), summarize, sum(Amount),.drop_i = F)
          tt1<-tt1[-1,]
          rrr<-rowSums(apply(tt1,2, as.numeric))
          tt1<-cbind(tt1,Total=rrr)
          cc<-colSums(apply(tt1, 2, as.numeric))
          tt1<-rbind(tt1,Total=cc)
          ECRR<-as.numeric(gsub(",","",e2[[2]][2,2]))-as.numeric(gsub(",","",e2[[2]][1,2]))
          if(ECRR<0){
            ECRR<-0
          } else {ECRR=ECRR}
          ECRR<-data.frame(ECRR)
          names(ECRR)<-"OMG"
          list(ECRR=ECRR,tt=tt,tt1=tt1,d1=d1)}
      })  
      output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
        return(!is.null(fund()))
      })
      outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
      name<-c("ECRR","tt","tt1","details")
      save.xlsx <- function (file, ...)
      {
        require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
        objects <- list(...)
        fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
        objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
        nobjects <- length(objects)
        for (i in 1:nobjects) {
          if (i == 1)
            write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = name[i])
          else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = name[i],
                          append = TRUE)
        }
        print(paste("Workbook", file, "has", nobjects, "worksheets."))
      }
      output$F<-renderTable({fund()$ECRR})
      output$G<-renderTable({fund()$tt},rownames=T)
      output$H<-renderTable({fund()$tt1},rownames=T)
      output$I<-renderTable({fund()$d1},rownames=T)
      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "ALM.xlsx",
        content = function(file) {
          save.xlsx(file,fund()$ECRR,fund()$tt,fund()$tt1,fund()$d1)
        }
      )
})
```

And ui.R

```
 library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar (
  headerPanel( "Fund"),
  sidebarPanel(width=3,
               fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file to upload',
                         accept = c(
                           '.pdf'
                         )),
               helpText("(Only .pdf files can be uploaded"),
               conditionalPanel("output.fileUploaded",
                                downloadButton('downloadData'))
  ),
  mainPanel (
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("ECRR", tableOutput("F")),
      tabPanel("Product wise Distribution", tableOutput("G")),
      tabPanel("Maturity wise Distribution", tableOutput("H")),
      tabPanel("Details", tableOutput("I"))
    ))
)
)
```

If anybody wants to test the files I am trying to upload here are 2 of them
[File1][1]

[File2][2]

Sorry for the very messy code and thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not tried your code, but I don't see any reason that the results should not be updated. What is the browser your are using ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried both in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. Here is the link of my app (https://khantanvir.shinyapps.io/check/), you can download the files and try.

Comment: I've tried. Even when I re-run the app with the other file, I get the same results. Are you sure that the two files are different, regarding the data you extract ?

Comment: Quite sure, when I run the code in my computer natively changing the file name in e1<-extract_tables( ), the results are fine. Even if I stop the instance in shiny and restart it and then upload a new file, the results are OK.

Comment: They are not exactly the same but they have many similarities. E.g you get `TRUE` if you do `e1 <- extract_tables("POSITION0412.pdf"); ee1 <- extract_tables("Position0712.pdf"); e1[[1]][35,4] == ee1[[1]][35,4]`.

Comment: Yes they are the investment report of two consecutive working days, they are close but there are differences. Do you know how to close and restart an instance of shiny by clicking a button or something?

Comment: I'm a bit sick and then lazy, maybe this is why I didn't see any difference between the results :)
Why not refreshing the page to restart the instance ? (with F5)
But again, it's not normal that the results are not updated, unless this is due to shinyapps. By the way we see that the app re-calculates something when we change the file (the screen becomes "pale" during a couple of seconds).

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort mate, but most probably its a known bug of tabulizer package https://github.com/ropenscilabs/tabulizer/issues/15

Comment: Weird. If you really want to force a resetting without doing F5, you could try the `reset` function of the `shinyjs` package.